# Weird status bar tint

Tags: android, android-statusbar

Where the action bar meets the status bar there is this weird tint or elevation.

Does anyone know where I could find the settings to change it?
Thanks

What it normally looks like:
[image: Click]

What it looks like now:
[image: Click]

Edit:
I am also running Cyanogenmod 13.

Comment: It's top shadow of toolbar/appbar in combination with transparent status bar. Dark blue color in place of status bar is provided by CoordinatorLayout or ScrimInsets*Layout.

Comment: Yep its using Coordinator. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where its adding that tint, but I was able to set it after it added back to normal

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setElevation(0);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
```